# Read Excel file into R with locked cells

Tags: r, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet to read into R, that is both password protected and has locked cells. I can use excel.link to import a password protected file, but I can't figure out how to unlock/unprotect the cells. excel.link gives me this error:

```
> <checkErrorInfo> 80020009  Error in top_left_corner[["CurrentRegion"]]
> :    You cannot use this command on a protected sheet. To use this
> command, you must first unprotect the sheet (Review tab, Changes
> group, Unprotect Sheet button). You may be prompted for a password.
> (Microsoft Excel)
```

Any advice is welcome. I can manually unprotect the cells, but I have to do this to hundreds of files on a daily basis.

My end goal here is to have the data from the 100s of spreadsheets imported into R for analytics. I do not need to export back into Excel. I also do not need to import the protected cells into R, so if there was a way to skip them that would work.

EDIT: New issue has emerged related to this operation. I get an error in R when I try to do the extraction on a shared workbook:

> 80020009  Error: Exception occurred.

If I manually go into Excel and unshare the workbook (under Review->Share Workbook->Uncheck Allow changes made by more than one user). Is there a way with excel.link to programmatically do this?

Comment: Can you provide more information?  Do you need to have changes saved to Excel, or do you just need to read the data into R?

Comment: Are the 100s of spreadsheets xls or xlsx? I have just recently gone thru hundreds of xlsx unzipping them, gsubbing out a line of xml protection, and zipping back up.

Comment: The files are all xlsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
library(excel.link)
filename = "shared.xlsx"
xl.workbook.open(filename, password = "test")
# here we resave workbook to the temporary folder with exclusive access
new_path = paste0(tempdir(), "\\", filename)
xl()[["Activeworkbook"]]$saveas(new_path, AccessMode=xl.constants$xlExclusive)
###
xl()[["Activesheet"]]$Unprotect(password = "test")
data = crc[a1]
xl.workbook.close()
unlink(new_path) # remove temporary Excel File
```

UPDATE 2018.07.16 Add code for saving workbook with exclusive access.

Comment: This is great. How does the "crc" line work? The excel.link documentation is hard to interpret. crc[a1] just gives me one cell, and when I try to select another cell or a range it freezes up RStudio.

Comment: @robin.datadrivers `cr` means that we read current region - it is region which you can select in excel when you are pressing Ctrl+Shift+*. Last 'c' means that we have column names in our region. So `cr[a1]` is current region without column names, `crrc[a1]` is current region with column and row names. Could you describe structure of your data? Is it rectangular region?

Comment: The worksheet I'm pulling from has some random cells with header information in the first few rows - the actual data I need to extract starts on cell A11, and is a rectangle from A11 to BA36.

Comment: @robin.datadrivers   It seems in your case it's better to use something like `data = xl[a11:ba36]` instead of `data = crc[a1]`.

Comment: I've added an edit above to see if you can help with this new issue.

Comment: @robin.datadrivers I can't reproduce issue with shared workbook - the code above works without any errors on my system. However, after some googling I find that we can save workbook without sharing. So I added code for saving workbook to temporary folder with exclusive access mode.